# SSH: Connection refused from windows but NOT from linux

Tags: networking, ssh, remote, putty

I have an issue when I try connecting to my Ubuntu server from local network. when I try to connect from my PC (static IP) with win7 and putty, I get

```
Network error:connection refused
```

But when I connect from my smartphone, everything is OK. Either from my wife's laptop (with win7 too).

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: can you ping the server from win 7 pc ?

Comment: Since this is cross-platform, it may be better to migrate it to [SuperUser](http://www.supueruser.com).

Comment: Right... So your saying it should work because it works from a Smartphone... Is it Android with [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot) or something?

Comment: [@nux: yes, i can
[@Dillmo: I don't understand you
[@wilf: Yes, Android with JuiceSSH

Comment: From the Windows PC, try using alternatives - OpenSSH or the Secure Shell client for Chrome browser.

Comment: Another thing - try disabling any firewalls, such as `firewall.cpl` or any anti-virus software that comes with a firewall.

Answer (score 2):

The Original poster found an answer:

I've found the issue: My "Virtualbox host interface" was set with the same IP of the server (don't know why, don't know how, trust me). Switching it to DHCP gave me back all connectivity!!!

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 7 machine that is not working likely has the same IP address as another device on the network. Move it to DHCP and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no, the only machine with that ip is my PC. But I use to use the same IP with win7 and with Ubuntu (in dual boot). Maybe this could be the issue?

Comment: Unlikely, as it is the same machine and would have the same MAC address. Maybe try a live Ubuntu USB on the PC and try connecting from it. Whether is works or not will give more information.